# DI into an object that is DI'd?

Tags: dependency-injection

I wanted to know if it's ok to try and dependency inject into a class that is dependency injected, something like:

```
class RootDependency{
}

class AnotherDependency{
      [InjectDecoratorForWhateverLibraryYouAreUsing]
      RootDependency injectedRoot;
}

// Inject AnotherDependency into a class...
class RandomClass{
      [InjectDecoratorForWhateverLibraryYouAreUsing]
      AnotherDependency itDepends;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is fine. This is how you build an object graph.

Dependency injection prefers you construct these objects as high up the call stack as you can. This is usually in main. But there is no limit that would prevent injecting A into B then B into C and so on.

One thing that might be worth noting. There is the Law of Demeter that says in this situation it's best if C only talks to (uses) A through B. It's not good for B to hand C a reference to A.

This is because Cs friend is B not A. Talk to your friends. Not friends of friends. It's better to let B worry about knowing how to use A. That lets it abstract away those details.

Respect that and you can make fairly complex object graphs without it turning into a tangled mess. Because the details of this complexity aren't spreading around.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer :) I've just started recently integrating dependency injection into my code and with a new hammer everything looks like a nail. I didn't want to mess it up in the future.

Comment: Also I totally agree with the law of Demeter, things could get very confusing if you start going down that path. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @meds DI is a fancy new term for reference passing. An old idea. I learned it way back in school when I learned Java. Couldn't print to a file without using it to make a print stream. Hated it. Now that I understand what it's getting me (polymorphism, and to not have to know the details of what I'm talking to) I feel much different about it.